# Testing whether a Lucene Query matches all the documents

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Given an instance of `Query` is it possible to somehow check whether that instance happens to represent a query that always matches all the documents in the index?

For example, a `MatchAllDocsQuery` or a `BooleanQuery` that contains a `MatchAllDocs` clause are such queries that always return all the documents. Another example is a `BooleanQuery` that has a SHOULD-match clause that has a nested SHOULD-match clause that has a `MatchAllDocs` inside it.

Note that a query that happens to return everything because it has all the possible terms in it or because the index is empty doesn't count as a query that always return all the documents. In other words, I would like to check whether a given query always returns everything no matter what the index contains.

Is it possible or at least approximately possible? I'll accept an answer with a solution that doesn't work for any conceivable case if it works for any query that can be returned from [Solr's Extended Dismax Query Parser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.ExtendedSolrQueryParser.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BooleanQuery` that contains a `MatchAllDocsQuery` as one of it's clauses doesn't necessarily return all documents, as the `BooleanQuery` may also contain other `MUST` or `MUST_NOT` clauses which would restrict the result set.  I don't believe there is anything the does this out of the box, and trying to handle any sort of query that Solr might split out would be difficult.  You would need to move through the queries recursively to ensure that everything effectively reduces to a `MatchAllDocsQuery`, ignoring scores.

Something like (this is entirely untested at this point):

```
boolean willMatchAll(Query query) {
    if (query instanceof MatchAllDocsQuery)
        return true;
    }
    else if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) {
        boolean foundMatchAll = false;
        for (BooleanClause clause : ((BooleanQuery)query).getClauses()) {
            if (clause.isProhibited()) {
                return false; //A reasonable assumption, that the MUST_NOT clauses won't be empty
            }
            else if (clause.isRequired()) {
                if (willMatchAll(clause.getQuery())) {
                    foundMatchAll = true;
                } else {
                    return false; //any MUST clause that is not a matchall means the boolean query will not match all
                }
            }
            else {
                if (willMatchAll(clause.getQuery())) {
                    foundMatchAll = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //If a matchall has been found, and we haven't return false yet, this boolean query matches all documents
        return foundMatchAll;
    }
    else if (query instanceof DisjunctionMaxQuery) {
        boolean isMatchAll = false
        //If any disjunct is a matchall, the query will match all documents
        for (Query subquery : ((DisjunctuionMaxQuery)query).getDisjuncts()) {
            isMatchAll = isMatchAll || willMatchAll(subquery);
        }
        return isMatchAll;
    }
    else if (query instanceof ConstantScoreQuery) {
        //Traverse right through ConstantScoreQuery.  The wrapper isn't of interest here.
        Query subquery = ((ConstantScoreQuery)query).getQuery()
        if (subquery == null) {
            return false; //It wraps a filter, not a query, and I don't believe a filter can be a matchall
        }
        return willMatchAll(subquery);
    }
    else {
        //No other standard queries may be or contain MatchAllDocsQueries, I don't believe.
        //Even a double open-ended range query restricts the results to those with a value in the specified field.
        return false; 
    }
}
```

And if you also wanted to handle the stuff in [`org.apache.lucene.queries`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queries/overview-summary.html), there would be more query types to handle, like `BoostingQuery` and `CustomScoreQuery`, among others.  But hopefully that gives some sort of idea on it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, i am wondering if you can do *:* search and get numFound and compare that  to see if your actual Query returns same numFound value. Am i missing something?

Comment: I believe this is probably the only easy solution here, but it doesn't really do what is asked.  This doesn't state whether the query is guaranteed to return all documents, only that it does on the data currently in the index (see the question's third paragraph)